# UITextView width greater than 512 doesn't show text

Tags: ipad, uitextview

Whenever I widen a UITextView to a size greater than 512, with code such as:

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 513, 1024)];
```

It doesn't display any text anymore... 512 works, any size below that too, but anything greater than 512 and it stops displaying any text. The full code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    RDLocalizedStrings * strings = [RDLocalizedStrings defaultLocalizedStrings];

    NSString* message = [strings getStringWithKey: @"noUpdatesAvailableText"];

    CGFloat messageFontSize;

    RDRectCreate(message);

    BOOL iPad = NO;
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif
    if (iPad) {
        RDRectWrite(message, 0, 100, 513, 200);
        messageFontSize = 20.0;
    } else {
        RDRectWrite(message, 0,  0, 320, 480);
        messageFontSize = 20.0;
    }

    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: messageRect];
    textView.text = message;
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: messageFontSize];
    textView.editable = NO;

    [self.view addSubview: textView];
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same problem (including the < 512px "solution") in a textview instantiated from a NIB. The odd thing is that the text is there (editable, selectable) but just not visible. After hitting enter in the textview, the text appears. Really odd.

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone, I had a similar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211133/ios-uitextview-not-displaying-correctly-bug

Answer (score 3):

It seem `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` make ipad's `UITextView` hide text. Resize with `textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,768,21)` can fix this.

Comment: If the current frame is already correct, simply specifying `textView.frame = textView.frame;` seems to work.