# ios UITextView not displaying correctly (bug?)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have 10 `UITextView`s laid out horizontally in a `UIScrollView` that has paging enabled.

when my view is initd and brought to view, the initial page's `UITextView`'s text does not appear. The background color shows up fine, but the text is not visible on screen.

Here's the phenomenon:

As soon as you drag the `UIScrollView` even **1px** the text *magically* displays it's self. What's the deal? How can I fix this?

** edit - code for kai **

```
[self.messageBodyTxt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSlab-300" size:16.67]];
[self.messageBodyTxt setText:[[data objectForKey:@"Description"] valueForKey:@"text"];
```

Note - I've already tried using a system font. Also, this code works on a different view so I'm not sure what'sup.

Comment: please post your code that instantiates the views.

Comment: try firing [self.scrollView setNeedsLayout] after the scrollView loads.

Comment: @Kai Most everything is done in IB except for setting the text and text's font (which I've now posted)
@Lefteris Good suggestion. I tried that and `setNeedsDisplay` and neither worked :(

Comment: Don't know about how and when "IB-code" is executed ... However a work around could be a programmatic scrolling 1px forth and back in viewDidLoad or somewhere else in the code after the view is shown... Whenever I had a problem with things not being displayed, I tried setNeedsLayout/Display and it never worked...

Comment: what is the width of the textview? I've had issues with text being hidden on [textviews wider than 512px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212894/uitextview-width-greater-than-512-doesnt-show-text).

Comment: @larsacus wtf.. that was it. I tried the answer you have and that didn't work for me. Did you find a solution? Let me know once you've seen this comment and I'll delete this question.

Comment: No, that really wasn't an answer at that link.  I haven't found a way around it except just to make the textview smaller than 512px and file a bug.

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution based on an answer in the linked post. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect f = self.myTextView.frame;
f.size.height += 1;
[self.myTextView setFrame:f];
```

Because my `UITextView` is already in a `XIB` file I just modify the existing height by 1px and viola. As @larsacus pointed out, this is only necessary when the module's width is over *512px*.