# Why is the text in my UITextView transparent until I press enter?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uitextview

This is the configuration of my textview

[image]

[image]

When I start typing in it I get this:

[image]

Until I press the return key, then I get this:
[image]

Has anybody got an idea as to why this happens? This is in iOS6, on the iPad, both in the Simulator as on the device

Comment: The text appear only with enter o with the blur too? i cann se that the texfield also change his background. You set the controller as delegate of textfield and have any delegate method?

Comment: I just took screenshots by drawing a rectangle on the simulator, that's why the 2 images are not identical. As long as I do not press enter the text does not appear. I can type multiple words on one line and it will stay invisible. The only delegate method I have is:

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

which simply returns YES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one contained the answer: [UITextView width greater than 512 doesn't show text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212894/uitextview-width-greater-than-512-doesnt-show-text?rq=1)

It seems that disabling the "flexible width" in the resize options of the UITextView solves the problem. Clearly a bug in UIKit methinks.

FYI my textview is 504 pixels wide.

Comment: on iOS 7 I also had issues (last line invisible) with `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` (had to switch to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`). The `textView` had 300 pixels width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textView.frame = textView.frame;
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer a better resource.