# UITextView transparent text issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextview

Googled abit, found out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212894/uitextview-width-greater-than-512-doesnt-show-text?rq=1) - UITextView with width > 512 does not show text

So re-setting the frame did make the appear - but now the UITextField does not scroll.

I tried using `setUserInteractions:YES` and `setScrollEnabled:YES`, still NO LUCK.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling on textView works only when the text size height > textView height else the scrolling will not work.

you should set thr frame (0,0,320,50) and the set a large text in this text field and then you can see the scrolling on textView